# Class Activity Calculator

Tags: javascript, html, css, calculator

### Introduction

[**Class Activity Calculator**](https://classactivitycalculator.github.io/) is an online application to calculate the students' class activity grades. The class activity grade (CA) is calculated based on the marks a student gets during the term. Here's a sample grade sheet we use in class:

[image]

Please review the source code and provide feedback.

### Adults: Old

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <meta name="description" content="Calculate the class activity grades of the ILI students.">
  <title>Class Activity Calculator</title>
  <link rel="icon" href="favicon.ico">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <img src="logo.png" alt="Logo">
    <h1>Class Activity Calculator</h1>
  </header>
  <nav>
    <a href="index.html" id="current">Adults: Old</a>
    <a href="adults-new.html">Adults: New</a>
    <a href="young-adults.html">Young Adults</a>
    <a href="kids.html">Kids</a>
  </nav>
  <main>
    <form autocomplete="off">
      <fieldset data-weight="4">
        <legend>Listening & Speaking</legend>
        <input type="number" step="any" min="0" max="100">
        <input type="number" step="any" min="0" max="100">
        <input type="number" step="any" min="0" max="100">
        <input type="number" step="any" min="0" max="100">
        <input type="number" step="any" min="0" max="100">
        <output></output>
      </fieldset>
      <fieldset data-weight="3">
        <legend>Reading</legend>
        <input type="number" step="any" min="0" max="100">
        <input type="number" step="any" min="0" max="100">
        <input type="number" step="any" min="0" max="100">
        <input type="number" step="any" min="0" max="100">
        <input type="number" step="any" min="0" max="100">
        <output></output>
      </fieldset>
      <fieldset data-weight="1">
        <legend>Writing</legend>
        <input type="number" step="any" min="0" max="100">
        <input type="number" step="any" min="0" max="100">
        <input type="number" step="any" min="0" max="100">
        <input type="number" step="any" min="0" max="100">
        <input type="number" step="any" min="0" max="100">
        <output></output>
      </fieldset>
      <div>
        <button type="button">Calculate</button>
        <output></output>
        <button type="reset">Reset</button>
      </div>
    </form>
  </main>
  <footer>
    Share on <a href="https://t.me/share/url?url=https%3A%2F%2Fclassactivitycalculator.github.io%2F&text=Class%20Activity%20Calculator%3A%20Calculate%20the%20class%20activity%20grades%20of%20the%20ILI%20students." title="Telegram: Share Web Page">Telegram</a> |
    <a href="https://www.facebook.com/dialog/share?app_id=2194746457255787&href=https%3A%2F%2Fclassactivitycalculator.github.io%2F" title="Post to Facebook">Facebook</a>
    <address><a href="https://t.me/MortezaMirmojarabian" title="Telegram: Contact @MortezaMirmojarabian" rel="author">Give feedback</a></address>
  </footer>
  <script>
    function setOutputValues() {
      var totalWeightedAverage = 0;
      var totalWeight = 0;
      var fieldsets = form.querySelectorAll('fieldset');
      for (var fieldset of fieldsets) {
        var average = averageInputValues(fieldset);
        var fieldsetOutput = fieldset.querySelector('output');
        if (average == undefined) {
          fieldsetOutput.value = 'You may only enter 0 to 100.';
        } else if (isNaN(average)) {
          fieldsetOutput.value = 'Please enter a grade.';
        } else {
          fieldsetOutput.value = 'avg: ' + average.toFixed(1);
        }
        totalWeightedAverage += average * fieldset.dataset.weight;
        totalWeight += Number(fieldset.dataset.weight);
      }
      var classActivity = totalWeightedAverage / totalWeight;
      var divOutput = form.querySelector('div output');
      if (isNaN(classActivity)) {
        divOutput.value = '';
      } else {
        divOutput.value = 'CA: ' + classActivity.toFixed(1);
      }
    }
  </script>
  <script src="global.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

### style.css

```
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

header {
  padding: 16px 0;
  text-align: center;
  background: linear-gradient(#999, #333);
}

img {
  width: 36px;
  height: 36px;
  vertical-align: bottom;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 1.125rem;
  font-family: 'Times New Roman';
  color: #FFF;
  text-shadow: 0 3px #000;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
}

nav {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  background: #333;
  border-top: 2px solid;
}

a {
  color: #FFF;
}

nav a {
  padding: 12px 6px;
  font: bold 0.75rem Verdana;
  text-decoration: none;
}

nav a:not(:last-child) {
  margin-right: 2px;
}

nav a:hover,
nav a:focus,
#current {
  outline: 0;
  border-top: 2px solid;
  margin-top: -2px;
}

main,
div {
  display: flex;
}

form {
  margin: 32px auto;
}

fieldset {
  margin: 0 0 16px;
  padding: 12px 12px 0;
  border: 1px solid #CCC;
  background: linear-gradient(#FFF, #CCC);
}

legend,
input,
output,
button {
  font-family: Arial;
}

legend,
button {
  color: #333;
}

legend {
  padding: 0 4px;
  font-size: 0.875rem;
}

input,
button,
div output {
  font-size: 0.833rem;
}

input {
  width: 4em;
}

input:invalid {
  outline: 1px solid red;
}

output {
  color: #C00;
}

fieldset output {
  display: block;
  margin: 8px 0 8px 6px;
  font-size: 0.75rem;
}

fieldset output::after {
  content: "\00A0";
}
/* a placeholder */

div output {
  margin: auto auto auto 6px;
}

footer {
  padding: 12px;
  background: #333;
  font: 0.75rem Arial;
  color: #FFF;
}

address {
  float: right;
}
```

### global.js

```
var form = document.querySelector('form');

function averageInputValues(fieldset) {
  var totalValue = 0;
  var totalNumber = 0;
  var inputs = fieldset.querySelectorAll('input');
  for (var input of inputs) {
    if (!input.validity.valid) {
      return;
    }
    totalValue += Number(input.value);
    totalNumber += Boolean(input.value);
  }
  return totalValue / totalNumber;
}

form.querySelector('[type="button"]').addEventListener('click', setOutputValues);

function detectChange() {
  var inputs = form.querySelectorAll('input');
  for (var input of inputs) {
    if (input.value) {
      return true;
    }
  }
}

form.querySelector('[type="reset"]').addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  if (detectChange() && !confirm('Your changes will be lost.\nAre you sure you want to reset?')) {
    event.preventDefault();
  }
});

window.addEventListener('beforeunload', function(event) {
  if (detectChange()) {
    event.returnValue = 'Your changes may be lost.';
  }
});
```

### Note

Please see the [**updates**](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/220503/33793).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Overall Assessment

Overall this code is fine but it has a lot of excess DOM queries. Those could be optimized using the tips below.

I noticed that if I calculate an average and then click the reset button, it still asks me to confirm when leaving the page. Should it still prompt to confirm even if the user has calculated an (overall) average?

### More specific feedback

It is confusing having `setOutputValues()` defined in the inline script whereas all other functions are declared in global.js. It would make more sense to have everything together, unless something is being abstracted into a module. But I see [your comment](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/220084/class-activity-calculator#comment425487_220185) that explains that `setOutputValues` will be different on each page. I would question what actually changes within that function depending on the page - is it the range values and/or strings? If so, perhaps those could be output as variables or else as hidden DOM elements.

---

I see some [ecmascript-6](/questions/tagged/ecmascript-6) features used, like [`for..of`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of), which means other features from that specification could be used as well. For instance, any variable that doesn't get re-assigned could be declared with [`const`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/const) and any value that does get re-assigned can be declared with [`let`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let).

---

I see the code queries for the form element:

> ```
> var form = document.querySelector('form');
> ```

I know that you were told "*`querySelectorAll` is your friend.*"<sup>[1](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/215201/120114)</sup>. However, use it with caution. There are other DOM query functions that run quicker than it. One could  add an `id` attribute to the element and query for it using `document.getElementById()`<sup>[2](https://www.sitepoint.com/community/t/getelementbyid-vs-queryselector/280663/2)</sup>. But then again, there is a reference to the [`forms`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/forms) property of `document`, which could remove the need to query the DOM altogether. The first form could be referenced via `document.forms[0]` or a name attribute could also be applied to allow reference by name.

For example, you could add the *name* attribute to the form:

```
<form autocomplete="off" name="activityCalc">
```

Then utilize that name when referencing `document.forms`:

```
  const form = document.forms.activityCalc;
```

That way there is no need to query the DOM with a function like `querySelector`.

The same is true for the `<output>` elements - a name could be added to the last one and then there is no need to query for that element when displaying the cumulative average, as well as the button labeled *Calculate*.

And instead of using `querySelectorAll()` to get the elements under a fieldset, you could use `.getElementsByTagName()` since the selector is just a tag name. As [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18247327/1575353) explains:

> `getElementsByTagName` is probably faster, since it is simpler, but that is unlikely to have a noticeable impact on anything you do with it.

---

I see that a handler for click events on the  reset button is added via

> ```
> form.querySelector('[type="reset"]').addEventListener('click', function(event) {...});
> ```

this can be simplified by using the [form event *reset*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/reset_event).

```
form.addEventListener('reset', function(event) { ... });
```

---

When loading a simple document like this with modern browsers it may be unlikely that the DOM would not be ready before the JavaScript code runs (depending on where it is included) but it is still wise to wait for the DOM to be ready before accessing DOM elements. This can be done with `document.addEventListener()` for the 'DOMContentLoaded` event. This also allows the scope of the variables to be limited to a callback function instead of global variables.

---

It is a best practice to use strict equality when comparing values.

On this line:

> ```
> if (average == undefined) {
> ```

the value for `average` is assigned the return value from `averageInputValues()` which will likely either be `undefined` or a floating point number that is the result of a division operation. Using strict equality comparison eliminates the need for the types to be checked. Use the strict equality operator here and anywhere else there is no need to convert types when comparing:

```
if (average === undefined) {
```

---

### Rewritten code

The code below uses advice from above to simplify some parts of the code.

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  //DOM queries/accesses run once
  const form = document.forms.activityCalc;
  const fieldsets = form.getElementsByTagName('fieldset');
  const inputs = form.getElementsByTagName('input');
  const divOutput = form.elements.classActivity;
  
  function setOutputValues() {
    let totalWeightedAverage = 0;
    let totalWeight = 0;
    for (const fieldset of fieldsets) {
      const average = averageInputValues(fieldset);

      // should there be handling for no output element found below?
      const fieldsetOutput = fieldset.getElementsByTagName('output')[0];
      if (average === undefined) {
        fieldsetOutput.value = 'You may only enter 0 to 100.';
      } else if (isNaN(average)) {
        fieldsetOutput.value = 'Please enter a grade.';
      } else {
        fieldsetOutput.value = 'avg: ' + average.toFixed(1);
      }
      totalWeightedAverage += average * fieldset.dataset.weight;
      totalWeight += Number(fieldset.dataset.weight);
    }
    const classActivity = totalWeightedAverage / totalWeight;
    if (isNaN(classActivity)) {
      divOutput.value = '';
    } else {
      divOutput.value = 'CA: ' + classActivity.toFixed(1);
    }
  }

  function averageInputValues(fieldset) {
    let totalValue = 0;
    let totalNumber = 0;
    const inputs = fieldset.getElementsByTagName('input');
    for (const input of inputs) {
      if (!input.validity.valid) {
        return;
      }
      totalValue += Number(input.value);
      totalNumber += Boolean(input.value);
    }
    return totalValue / totalNumber;
  }

  form.elements.calculate.addEventListener('click', setOutputValues);

  function detectChange() {
    for (const input of inputs) {
      if (input.value) {
        return true;
      }
    }
  }

  form.addEventListener('reset', function(event) {
    if (detectChange() && !confirm('Your changes will be lost.\nAre you sure you want to reset?')) {
      event.preventDefault();
    }
  });

  window.addEventListener('beforeunload', function(event) {
    if (detectChange()) {
      event.returnValue = 'Your changes may be lost.';
    }
  });
});
```

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

header {
  padding: 16px 0;
  text-align: center;
  background: linear-gradient(#999, #333);
}

img {
  vertical-align: bottom;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 1.125rem;
  font-family: 'Times New Roman';
  color: #FFF;
  text-shadow: 0 3px #000;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
}

nav {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  background: #333;
  border-top: 2px solid;
}

a {
  color: #FFF;
}

nav a {
  padding: 12px 6px;
  font: bold 0.75rem Verdana;
  text-decoration: none;
}

nav a:not(:last-child) {
  margin-right: 2px;
}

nav a:hover,
nav a:focus,
#current {
  outline: 0;
  border-top: 2px solid;
  margin-top: -2px;
}

main,
div {
  display: flex;
}

form {
  margin: 32px auto;
}

fieldset {
  margin: 0 0 16px;
  padding: 12px 12px 0;
  border: 1px solid #CCC;
  background: linear-gradient(#FFF, #CCC);
}

legend,
input,
output,
button {
  font-family: Arial;
}

legend,
button {
  color: #333;
}

legend {
  padding: 0 4px;
  font-size: 0.875rem;
}

input,
button,
div output {
  font-size: 0.833rem;
}

input {
  width: 4em;
}

input:invalid {
  outline: 1px solid red;
}

output {
  color: #C00;
}

fieldset output {
  display: block;
  margin: 8px 0 8px 6px;
  font-size: 0.75rem;
}

fieldset output::after {
  content: "\00A0";
}


/* a placeholder */

div output {
  margin: auto auto auto 6px;
}

footer {
  padding: 12px;
  background: #333;
  font: 0.75rem Arial;
  color: #FFF;
}

address {
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <img src="https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/codereview/img/logo.svg?v=0dfb1294dc6e" alt="Logo">
  <h1>Class Activity Calculator</h1>
</header>
<nav>
  <a href="index.html" id="current">Adults: Old</a>
  <a href="adults-new.html">Adults: New</a>
  <a href="young-adults.html">Young Adults</a>
  <a href="kids.html">Kids</a>
</nav>
<main>
  <form autocomplete="off" name="activityCalc">
    <fieldset data-weight="4">
      <legend>Listening & Speaking</legend>
      <input type="number" step="any" min="0" max="100">
      <input type="number" step="any" min="0" max="100">
      <input type="number" step="any" min="0" max="100">
      <input type="number" step="any" min="0" max="100">
      <input type="number" step="any" min="0" max="100">
      <output></output>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset data-weight="3">
      <legend>Reading</legend>
      <input type="number" step="any" min="0" max="100">
      <input type="number" step="any" min="0" max="100">
      <input type="number" step="any" min="0" max="100">
      <input type="number" step="any" min="0" max="100">
      <input type="number" step="any" min="0" max="100">
      <output></output>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset data-weight="1">
      <legend>Writing</legend>
      <input type="number" step="any" min="0" max="100">
      <input type="number" step="any" min="0" max="100">
      <input type="number" step="any" min="0" max="100">
      <input type="number" step="any" min="0" max="100">
      <input type="number" step="any" min="0" max="100">
      <output></output>
    </fieldset>
    <div>
      <button type="button" name="calculate">Calculate</button>
      <output name="classActivity"></output>
      <button type="reset">Reset</button>
    </div>
  </form>
</main>
<footer>
  Share on <a href="https://t.me/share/url?url=https%3A%2F%2Fclassactivitycalculator.github.io%2F&text=Class%20Activity%20Calculator%3A%20Calculate%20the%20class%20activity%20grades%20of%20the%20ILI%20students." title="Telegram: Share Web Page">Telegram</a>  |
  <a href="https://www.facebook.com/dialog/share?app_id=2194746457255787&href=https%3A%2F%2Fclassactivitycalculator.github.io%2F" title="Post to Facebook">Facebook</a>
  <address><a href="https://t.me/MortezaMirmojarabian" title="Telegram: Contact @MortezaMirmojarabian" rel="author">Give feedback</a></address>
</footer>
```

---

<sup>1</sup><sub>https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/215201/120114</sub>

<sup>2</sup><sub>https://www.sitepoint.com/community/t/getelementbyid-vs-queryselector/280663/2</sub>

Comment: Thanks for the detailed review! "_what actually changes within that function depending on the page - is it the range values and/or strings?_" The `max` and `weight` values (no `weight`s on two pages), and the _CA_ ranges. I can't find a short way to generalize `setOutputValues()`. "_should there be handling for no output element found below?_" I'm not sure I understand what you mean. Each `fieldset` has an `output`.

Comment: No `weight` and a `weight` == 1 is the same so you could go with this (if you don't want to test if `weight` exist in `setOutputValues`). For the `max` you really just need to do exactly like you did for the `weight` (set a `data-max` and use it). The CA range is taking care of itself (with your `for`), in fact `setOutputValues()` is already mostly generalized really. For the `output `part he wanted to know if there was a need to test if `output` existed (you answered it).

Comment: @Nomis: "_No `weight` and a `weight` == 1 is the same so you could go with this_" Please see the [updates](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/220503/33793).

Answer (score 1):

**Edit : as asked, I've edited my code to make a good proof of concept. I've also adapted it to the reworked version of the script, since it doesn't really matter.**

Well, I'm lazy and I love to let my script do all the work for me. And you should too !

So instead of `index`, `adults-new`, `young-adults` and `kids` having one page each, how about something like that :

```js
var listForm={
 'adult_old':{
  'Listening & Speaking':{'weight':4,'fields':5,'max':100},
  'Reading':{'weight':3,'fields':5,'max':100},
  'Writing':{'weight':1,'fields':5,'max':100}
 },
 'adult_young':{
  'Listening':{'weight':4,'fields':4,'max':5},
  'Speaking':{'weight':3,'fields':4,'max':5},
  'Reading':{'weight':2,'fields':4,'max':5},
  'Writing':{'weight':1,'fields':4,'max':5},
 }
};
var form = document.querySelector('form');

function toggleForm(formSelected){
  let myForm=listForm[formSelected];
  let formContent='';
  for(activity in myForm){
    var myActivity=myForm[activity];
    formContent+='<fieldset data-weight="'+myActivity['weight']+'">';
    formContent+='<legend>'+activity+'</legend>';
    for(i=0;i<myActivity['fields'];i++)formContent+='<input type="number" step="any" min="0" max="'+myActivity['max']+'">';
    formContent+='<output></output></fieldset>';
  }
  document.getElementById('classActivity').innerHTML=formContent;
}

function averageInputValues(fieldset) {
  var totalValue = 0;
  var totalNumber = 0;
  var inputs = fieldset.querySelectorAll('input');
  for (var input of inputs) {
    if (!input.validity.valid) {
      return;
    }
    totalValue += Number(input.value);
    totalNumber += Boolean(input.value);
  }
  return totalValue / totalNumber;
}

function setOutputValues() {
  var max = form.querySelector('input').max;
  var totalWeightedAverage = 0;
  var totalWeight = 0;
  var fieldsets = form.querySelectorAll('fieldset');
  for (var fieldset of fieldsets) {
    var average = averageInputValues(fieldset);
    var fieldsetOutput = fieldset.querySelector('output');
    if (average == undefined) {
      fieldsetOutput.value = 'You may only enter 0 to ' + max + '.';
    } else if (isNaN(average)) {
      fieldsetOutput.value = 'Please enter a grade.';
    } else {
      fieldsetOutput.value = 'avg: ' + average.toFixed(1);
    }
    var weight = fieldset.dataset.weight;
    if (!weight) {
      weight = 1;
    }
    totalWeightedAverage += average * weight;
    totalWeight += Number(weight);
  }
  var classActivity = totalWeightedAverage / totalWeight;
  var divOutput = document.getElementById('total_output');
  if (isNaN(classActivity)) {
    divOutput.value = '';
  } else if (max == 5) { // Adults: New
    divOutput.value = 'CA: ' + (classActivity / (max / 100)).toFixed(1); // The class activity grade must be calculated out of 100.
  } else {
    divOutput.value = 'CA: ' + classActivity.toFixed(1);
  }
}

function detectChange() {
  var inputs = form.querySelectorAll('input');
  for (var input of inputs) {
    if (input.value) {
      return true;
    }
  }
}

var nav_items=document.querySelectorAll('.nav_item');
for (var nav_item of nav_items) {
  nav_item.addEventListener('click', function(){
    document.querySelector('.current').classList.remove('current');
    this.classList.add('current');
    toggleForm(this.id); 
   });
}
toggleForm('adult_old');//default form

form.querySelector('[type="button"]').addEventListener('click', setOutputValues);

form.addEventListener('reset', function(event) {
  if (detectChange() && !confirm('Your changes will be lost.\nAre you sure you want to reset?')) {
    event.preventDefault();
  }
});

window.addEventListener('beforeunload', function(event) {
  if (detectChange()) {
    event.returnValue = 'Your changes may be lost.';
  }
});
```

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

header {
  padding: 16px 0;
  text-align: center;
  background: linear-gradient(#999, #333);
}

img {
  width: 36px;
  height: 36px;
  vertical-align: bottom;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 1.125rem;
  font-family: 'Times New Roman';
  color: #FFF;
  text-shadow: 0 3px #000;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
}

nav {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  background: #333;
  border-top: 2px solid;
}

span {
  color: #FFF;
}

nav span {
  padding: 12px 6px;
  font: bold 0.75rem Verdana;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor:pointer;
}

nav span:not(:last-child) {
  margin-right: 2px;
}

nav span:hover,
nav span:focus,
.current {
  outline: 0;
  border-top: 2px solid;
  margin-top: -2px;
}

main,
div {
  display: flex;
}

form {
  margin: 32px auto;
}

fieldset {
  margin: 0 0 16px;
  padding: 12px 12px 0;
  border: 1px solid #CCC;
  background: linear-gradient(#FFF, #CCC);
}

legend,
input,
output,
button {
  font-family: Arial;
}

legend,
button {
  color: #333;
}

legend {
  padding: 0 4px;
  font-size: 0.875rem;
}

input,
button,
div output {
  font-size: 0.833rem;
}

input {
  width: 4em;
}

input:invalid {
  outline: 1px solid red;
}

output {
  color: #C00;
}

fieldset output {
  display: block;
  margin: 8px 0 8px 6px;
  font-size: 0.75rem;
}

fieldset output::after {
  content: "\00A0";
}
/* a placeholder */

div output {
  margin: auto auto auto 6px;
}

footer {
  padding: 12px;
  background: #333;
  font: 0.75rem Arial;
  color: #FFF;
}

address {
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <meta name="description" content="Calculate the class activity grades of the ILI students.">
  <title>Class Activity Calculator</title>
  <link rel="icon" href="favicon.ico">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <img src="logo.png" alt="Logo">
    <h1>Class Activity Calculator</h1>
  </header>
  <nav>
    <span class="nav_item current" id="adult_old">Adults: Old</span>
    <span class="nav_item" id="adult_young">Young Adults</span>
  </nav>
  <main>
    <form autocomplete="off">
      <div id="classActivity" style="display:block;"></div><!--didn't want to touch the css-->
      <div>
        <button type="button">Calculate</button>
        <output id="total_output"></output>
        <button type="reset">Reset</button>
      </div>
    </form>
  </main>
  <footer>
    Share on <a href="https://t.me/share/url?url=https%3A%2F%2Fclassactivitycalculator.github.io%2F&text=Class%20Activity%20Calculator%3A%20Calculate%20the%20class%20activity%20grades%20of%20the%20ILI%20students." title="Telegram: Share Web Page">Telegram</a> |
    <a href="https://www.facebook.com/dialog/share?app_id=2194746457255787&href=https%3A%2F%2Fclassactivitycalculator.github.io%2F" title="Post to Facebook">Facebook</a>
    <address><a href="https://t.me/MortezaMirmojarabian" title="Telegram: Contact @MortezaMirmojarabian" rel="author">Give feedback</a></address>
  </footer>
</body>

</html>
```

That way, you'll only need to change the object at the start if an activity (or class, or evaluation) is added or removed.

You should also put all your JS in `global.js` (or another file if you use `global.js` somewhere else, but I don't think so), it's good practice.

Comment: "_instead of `index`, `adults-new`, `young-adults` and `kids` having one page each, how about something like that_" Using JavaScript to dynamically create content would be beneficial if I had the same HTML across my site pages. As you see on [Kids](https://classactivitycalculator.github.io/kids.html), I don't have even the same number of `input`s in each `fieldset` of the same page. "_You should also put all your JS in `global.js`_" I can't as the `setOutputValues` function is different on each page. My `global.js` file includes only what the pages have in common.

Comment: Err, guess I should have called `fields` `input_number` instead, my bad ^^ I just swapped `adult_old` and `adult_young` (and changed the `fields` number) in my example as to show the number of inputs adapting. Likewise, if your only difference in `setOutputValues` is the max value of each input, you can just add another attribute (`max`) in the `listForm` object.

Answer (score 1):

### Updates

- Simplified

  ```
  form.querySelector('[type="reset"]').addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  ```

  to

  ```
  form.addEventListener('reset', function(event) {
  ```

  Thanks @Sᴀᴍ Onᴇᴌᴀ
- Generalized `setOutputValues()` mainly by adding a `weight` to the rest of the `fieldset`s:

  ```
  var weight = fieldset.dataset.weight;
  if (!weight) {weight = 1;}
  ```

  Thanks @Nomis
- Simplified

  ```
  divOutput.value = 'CA: ' + (classActivity / (max / 100)).toFixed(1);
  ```

  to

  ```
  divOutput.value = 'CA: ' + (classActivity * 100 / max).toFixed(1);
  ```

### script.js

```
var form = document.querySelector('form');

function averageInputValues(fieldset) {
  var totalValue = 0;
  var totalNumber = 0;
  var inputs = fieldset.querySelectorAll('input');
  for (var input of inputs) {
    if (!input.validity.valid) {
      return;
    }
    totalValue += Number(input.value);
    totalNumber += Boolean(input.value);
  }
  return totalValue / totalNumber;
}

function setOutputValues() {
  var max = form.querySelector('input').max;
  var totalWeightedAverage = 0;
  var totalWeight = 0;
  var fieldsets = form.querySelectorAll('fieldset');
  for (var fieldset of fieldsets) {
    var average = averageInputValues(fieldset);
    var fieldsetOutput = fieldset.querySelector('output');
    if (average == undefined) {
      fieldsetOutput.value = 'You may only enter 0 to ' + max + '.';
    } else if (isNaN(average)) {
      fieldsetOutput.value = 'Please enter a grade.';
    } else {
      fieldsetOutput.value = 'avg: ' + average.toFixed(1);
    }
    var weight = fieldset.dataset.weight;
    if (!weight) {
      weight = 1;
    }
    totalWeightedAverage += average * weight;
    totalWeight += Number(weight);
  }
  var classActivity = totalWeightedAverage / totalWeight;
  var divOutput = form.querySelector('div output');
  if (isNaN(classActivity)) {
    divOutput.value = '';
  } else if (max == 5) { // Adults: New
    divOutput.value = 'CA: ' + (classActivity * 100 / max).toFixed(1); // The class activity grade must be calculated out of 100.
  } else {
    divOutput.value = 'CA: ' + classActivity.toFixed(1);
  }
}

form.querySelector('[type="button"]').addEventListener('click', setOutputValues);

function detectChange() {
  var inputs = form.querySelectorAll('input');
  for (var input of inputs) {
    if (input.value) {
      return true;
    }
  }
}

form.addEventListener('reset', function(event) {
  if (detectChange() && !confirm('Your changes will be lost.\nAre you sure you want to reset?')) {
    event.preventDefault();
  }
});

window.addEventListener('beforeunload', function(event) {
  if (detectChange()) {
    event.returnValue = 'Your changes may be lost.';
  }
});
```

### Adults: Old

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <meta name="description" content="Calculate the class activity grades of the ILI students.">
  <title>Class Activity Calculator</title>
  <link rel="icon" href="favicon.ico">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <img src="logo.png" alt="Logo">
    <h1>Class Activity Calculator</h1>
  </header>
  <nav>
    <a href="index.html" id="current">Adults: Old</a>
    <a href="adults-new.html">Adults: New</a>
    <a href="young-adults.html">Young Adults</a>
    <a href="kids.html">Kids</a>
  </nav>
  <main>
    <form autocomplete="off">
      <fieldset data-weight="4">
        <legend>Listening & Speaking</legend>
        <input type="number" step="any" min="0" max="100">
        <input type="number" step="any" min="0" max="100">
        <input type="number" step="any" min="0" max="100">
        <input type="number" step="any" min="0" max="100">
        <input type="number" step="any" min="0" max="100">
        <output></output>
      </fieldset>
      <fieldset data-weight="3">
        <legend>Reading</legend>
        <input type="number" step="any" min="0" max="100">
        <input type="number" step="any" min="0" max="100">
        <input type="number" step="any" min="0" max="100">
        <input type="number" step="any" min="0" max="100">
        <input type="number" step="any" min="0" max="100">
        <output></output>
      </fieldset>
      <fieldset>
        <legend>Writing</legend>
        <input type="number" step="any" min="0" max="100">
        <input type="number" step="any" min="0" max="100">
        <input type="number" step="any" min="0" max="100">
        <input type="number" step="any" min="0" max="100">
        <input type="number" step="any" min="0" max="100">
        <output></output>
      </fieldset>
      <div>
        <button type="button">Calculate</button>
        <output></output>
        <button type="reset">Reset</button>
      </div>
    </form>
  </main>
  <footer>
    Share on <a href="https://t.me/share/url?url=https%3A%2F%2Fclassactivitycalculator.github.io%2F&text=Class%20Activity%20Calculator%3A%20Calculate%20the%20class%20activity%20grades%20of%20the%20ILI%20students." title="Telegram: Share Web Page">Telegram</a> |
    <a href="https://www.facebook.com/dialog/share?app_id=2194746457255787&href=https%3A%2F%2Fclassactivitycalculator.github.io%2F" title="Post to Facebook">Facebook</a>
    <address><a href="https://t.me/MortezaMirmojarabian" title="Telegram: Contact @MortezaMirmojarabian" rel="author">Give feedback</a></address>
  </footer>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: If it wasn't for those meddling kids with there 60 max, you could get away with only `divOutput.value = 'CA: ' + (classActivity / (max / 100)).toFixed(1);` for every classes in your last condition, since 100/100=1. Also, do you want me to update my example to show you how you could use only one page or is it clearer now ?

Comment: @Nomis: "_If it wasn't for those meddling kids with there 60 max, you could get away with only `divOutput.value = 'CA: ' + (classActivity / (max / 100)).toFixed(1);` for every classes in your last condition, since 100/100=1._" Exactly! "_Also, do you want me to update my example to show you how you could use only one page or is it clearer now?_" Yes, please: It will be useful at least for future reference.

Comment: There you go, now my previous answer is alive (work on click). I made some adaptations to get a bug-free, similar-looking screen. On that note you should try to use more ids and classes and less tags in your `querySelector` (I had to change the `div output` one).